# How to find an element in this page using Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

I'm trying to find the selected element on this page (see attachment), but I could not find it. I use findelementById and ByXPath, but it did not work. I think I need to focus on the right area. How do I do that? When I select the area on the left, I can not select elements in the area on the right, and vice versa.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts4RI.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code so far. The comments and some other parts are in Portuguese (my native language).
    driver.Quit

```
VarPrimeiraParte = Planilha1.Range("A2:A2").Value
VarSegundaParte = Planilha1.Range("B2:B2").Value

'O código abaixo configura o Firefox para fazer os downloads de PDFs automaticamente ao serem visualizados.
'driver.SetProfile "Download", persistant:=True ' Added
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.folderList", 2
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.dir", "C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\DownTJ" & Planilha1.Range("A2:A2").Value & "." & Planilha1.Range("B2:B2").Value
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False
driver.SetPreference "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel, application/x-download, application/msword, application/msexcel, application/xls, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream"
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.useDownloadDir", True
driver.SetPreference "browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False
driver.SetPreference "browser.download.manager.useWindow", False
driver.SetPreference "services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False
driver.SetPreference "pdfjs.disabled", True

'Abre o navegador com a paginá de login do TJRJ.
driver.Get "https://www3.tjrj.jus.br/segweb/faces/login.jsp?indGet=true&SIGLASISTEMA=PORTALSERV"

'Seleciona os elementos para inserção do texto do login e da senha, clicando em Enviar em seguida.
driver.FindElementById("txtLogin").SendKeys ("999999999")
driver.FindElementById("txtSenha").SendKeys ("XXXXXX")
driver.FindElementById("btnEnviar").Click

driver.SwitchToNextWindow
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='ext-gen290']/li[1]/div/a/span").Click

THIS IS THE ERROR:
'driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='parte1ProcCNJ']").SendKeys VarPrimeiraParte
```